# Markov Chain/Matrix from previous multiple independent states that only one (not both) need to be true.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, markov-chains

I am trying to solve this problem generally; let’s say you roll a D6 a 9 times, you record these results and put them into a 3x3 matrix like so:

{

{r1, r2, r3},

{r4, r5, r6},

{r7, r8, r9}

}

What is the probability (number of true outcomes/total number of outcomes) that when reading the matrix, that any verticals (column) or horizontal (row) has all 5’s.

So a true some true cases are:

{

{5,3,6},

{5,5,5},

{1,2,4}

}

because the second row has all 5’s.

Also true is:

{

{5,5,5},

{5,5,1},

{5,5,5}

}

because the first and third rows hit the criteria, and the first and second columns hit the criteria, only one row or column needs to meet the criteria.

I feel like there should be a way to do this using Markov Chains, but I am unable to come or find a method of doing so.  Even though I feel like there is a way, I suspect there is also no way to do it.

I have tried to unwrap the matrix in its untransposed form and transposed form, but I get the issue of something like this {4,3,5,5,5,1,6,6,2} being a false positive, because the three 5’s are not in the same row or column, but do appear next to each other when unwrapped.

What I obviously do know, is that for this example, there 6^9 or 10,077,696 possible matrices (not taking into account symmetries).  A fraction of these are then true.

Comment: You might find it easier to consider $2^9=512$ possible patterns (each cell $5$ or not $5$) taking account of the fact they are not equally likely

Comment: @henry I can brute force that pretty easily, but I am wanting to find a general solution for any sided die (not just n=2) for any size matrix.

Comment: I also know that there must be a recursive relationship.

Answer (score 1):

For $i=1,2,3$ let $R_i$ denotes the events that row $i$ meets the criteria.

For $i=1,2,3$ let $C_i$ denotes the events that column $i$ meets the criteria.

Also denote the event that all entries will be a $5$ by $A$.

Observe that $A=R_1\cap R_2\cap R_2=C_1\cup C_2\cap C_3$.

To be found is: $$P(R_1\cup R_2\cup R_3\cup C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3)$$

Applying inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:$$\dots=6P(R_1)-[6P(R_1\cap R_2)+9P(R_1\cap C_1)]+[2P(A)+18P(R_1\cap R_2\cap C_1)]-[6P(A)+9P(R_1\cap R_2\cap C_1\cap C_2)]+6P(A)-P(A)$$

Here:

- $P(R_1)=6^{-3}$,
- $P(R_1\cap R_2)=6^{-6}$,
- $P(R_1\cap C_1)=6^{-5}$,
- $P(R_1\cap R_2\cap C_1)=6^{-7}$,
- $P(R_1\cap R_2\cap C_1\cap C_2)=6^{-8}$
- $P(A)=6^{-9}$